# Как ещё можно написать данный код?

Tags: php

Есть такой метод, который принимает множество аргументов.

```
public function load(...$objs) {
   foreach ($objs as $obj) $this->test($obj);
}
```

Вызываваю вот так

```
$this->load(new Obj1, new Obj2);
```

Вот как можно написать ещё метод load без foreach? На что можно его заменить? Правильно ли написан такой код?

Comment: "Вызываваю вот так"  --- сделать передачу массива и не извращаться..... и принятие массива... зачем эти пляски?........... "как можно написать ещё метод load без foreach"  --- никак......"Правильно ли написан такой код?" --- а что тут оценивать....... когда будет код из строчек 100 хотя бы тогда и надо смотреть.. а это в отрыве от контекста непонятно что непонятно зачем

Comment: @АлексейШиманский - " --- никак......" - ошибаетесь: array_map($this->test, $objs);

Comment: @Виктор считай что это тоже цикл foreach, т.к. в любом случае тут происходит перебор всех значений от начала массива и до конца

Comment: foreach всё таки медленнее чем map, ещё array_filter. Это как вопрос на собеседовании:)

Comment: @Виктор на чём основано утверждение, что array_map быстрее, чем foreach? array_filter вообще не в тему... вы завалили собеседование в таком случае, раз предлагаете неподходящий метод куда не нужно ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АлексейШиманский "array_filter вообще не в тему" - с чего это? Я не могу вызвать из него подпрограмму? Поповоду foreach https://medium.com/@visheshahuja/php-array-map-vs-foreach-loop-18488c95aa18 Мыслить шире надо:)

Comment: @Виктор если бы вы мне такое на собседовании сказали про filter - я бы вас не взял..... да, конечно, можно суп и шумовкой кушать (ложка с дырками), а из пушки по воробьям стрельять, но действие это совершенно бессмысленное....... А производительность во-первых: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64460563/6104996  и https://stackoverflow.com/a/64460563/6104996 посвежее (2020) . во-вторых надо сравнивать ещё версии пыхи,  в-третьих еще различие что это fpm или другое...В целом факторов я бы сказал даже много. Но пока выигрывает именно foreach....

Comment: @Виктор в общем стОит использовать инструменты **по назначению**, а не "мыслить шире", вам кажется, что это какая-то многогранность и креативность, а другие разработчики вас засмеют просто.... странно что array_reducе не упомянули... или array_walk.... да что уж, array_walk_recursive совсем отлично!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вы от вопроса отвлеклисть: "Вот как можно написать ещё метод load без foreach? На что можно его заменить?" Если у Вас нет вариантов, то я Вам сочувствую

Comment: @Виктор ТС  скорее всего имеет в виду "не используя циклы", нежели "переписать это любым способом, лишь бы не видеть это слово перед глазами"